# Any way to fix the horrible performance?

Tags: pc, watch-dogs

So to anyone who bought Watch_Dogs on release date for PC would have been extremely disappointed to find that their top notch gaming rigs can't even sustain a smooth 30fps on low-mid settings. All fingers pointed to ubisoft and their rubbish port from console to PC causing these performance issues.

The game has been out for a solid 2-3 months (I've lost count) and ubisoft have to have noticed whats going on here. So has there been any sort of patch released to fix this issue?

Background info, bought the game on steam which forces me to play through uplay. Neither one of them have prompted me for a game update, leading me to assume that ubisoft have not released a patch of any kind (bastards).

If there has been a fix of any kind? How do I find/implement such fix?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What are your system specifications?

Comment: When I originally got watch_dogs, I had been using my r9 270x because my gtx 670 was super laggy for games like league of legends. The 270x couldn't even hold a playable framerate on minimum settings. I had to wipe my ssd about a month ago and I decided to put my 670 back in and, while league of legends still lags, watch_dogs is buttery smooth on maximum settings. In my experience,  there isn't much that you can do other than swapping out hardware.

Comment: @TZHX I'm running an Intel i7-4930k and an R9 290x. 16GB DDR3 G-skill RAM (1600MHz) on an Asus X79-Deluxe mobo and quad 2TB barracudas in RAID 10. I mean these specs tank out even some of the most demanding games out on the market like BF4, Metro: Last Night and Far Cry 3 well above 60fps. Why must watch dogs be an exception?

Comment: Because watch_dogs is just not optimized for PC. TotalBiscuit's dual GTX TITAN BLACK couldn't 1080p 60 fps version 1.0 of Watch_Dogs, don't know about now. I just learn to accept the fact that I can't 60 fps it. Also, considering that Watch_Dogs is an nVIDIA Gameworks game, using nVIDIA hardware should provide a lot of help

Comment: Yeah I've heard about that. I've also been told that the game has the HQ PC textures that were shown at E3, but instead ubisoft are using the console scaled down textures instead. Seriously Watch_Dogs is just a total flop in the PC world and actually disappoints me quite a lot :(

Comment: I have a fairly good graphics card and the game lagged extremely while driving. You can set the Graphic Quality in the Display-Menu in the Settings. Dont use the Ultra-Settibgs but the one below. (The Setting tells you how much GPU you need. You're in the wrong menu if the setting doesnt tell you this. Ultra is 3GB GPU and High is 2GB GPU. The Ultra Settings are still glitched

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what you've been doing, but there are patcheS (Yes, more than one) out for Watch-dogs more than a month ago.

Little Background for you:

Ubisoft did port the game from console but the next-gen consoles. The problem was that the next-gen consoles use unified memory. PC, on the other hand, uses memory individually that is; theres your RAM and then theres the Memory of your GPU. This was a major issue.
The most criticism has been drawn to poor AI, game glitches, shadows and lightning.
Ubisoft announced a couple days after game launch itself that the game will receive patches soon, and the patches have been available quite some time now.

Solution for lags:

- Patch. It fixes more than half the issues you are facing.
- Lower textures.
- Lower resolution.
- Lower Anti-Aliasing.

Hope this helped! Happy Gamin'!

Comment: Hmm very odd. Steam says the game is up to date, yet I'm still getting horrible lag. I'll keep looking into it though. Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: Weird. But, I think the reason steam says its up-to-date is because WD is played via Uplay. Uplay should update it, or you can try it manually via Ubisoft's website. Your welcome!

Comment: Yeah I've tried seeing if uplay would have any updates available, nada. If only all gaming platforms melded into one giant gelatinous ooze where everything just worked without any problems. Ah well I don't play it much anymore anyway so I guess this doesn't bother me as much as it initially did.

Answer (score -1):

You have to run it on windowed mode. And lower the max buffered frames..first open task manager. Then End unnecessary Tasks. Go to details and end unnecessary processes. then end task - explorer.exe i.e. windows explorer. then click file > run new task. go to browse and open watchdogs.exe from the game directory. then end task - task manager...there will be less stuttering..

after exiting the game, press ctrl-alt-del, then click run task manager. then click file > run new task..there type explorer.exe..